# My ImageHandler doesn't work

Tags: asp.net, ashx

I am trying to code a simple handler that should return an image URL so that I can display it on my website. This is how my handler looks like:

```
<%@ WebHandler Language="C#" Class="KameraHandler" %>

using System;
using System.Web;

public class KameraHandler : IHttpHandler {

    public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) {
        context.Response.Write("http://web.scott.k12.va.us/martha2/dmbtest.gif");
    }

    public bool IsReusable {
        get {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

and this is how I call my handler but It just doesn' work.

```
protected void AraLinkButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     KameraImage.Src = "~/GenericHandler/KameraHandler.ashx;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your image handler is supposed to return the raw bytes of an image (and with the appropriate `Content-Type`), not the URL of an image.

You should set the `src` directly to that (external) URL.

Alternatively, you could make your ASHX send a redirect to that URL, or make it forward the contents of that URL.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to download the image from that other URL and write its bytes out. Also you need to set the MIME type.